# Multiple selection made via list box in uitable

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a uitable and originally last two columns work as popup menus which allows only one selection.

```
uitable('blah blah blah',...
        'ColumnFormat'{'logical','char',cell_array1,cell_array2},...
        'ColumnEditable',[true false true true],...
        'Data',[blah blah cell_array2 cell_array2])
```

Now my customer wants to be able to make multiple selections (by holding down CTRL or whatever).

My understanding is that popup menu does not allow multiselect, but listbox does.

I couldn't find a way to put listboxes in a uitable.

I'm open to any other means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only so much you can do with Matlab uicontrols / uitable etc. You would get ultimate flexibility if you just resort to pure java solutions, e.g. wonderful swing-based [JIDE Grids](https://www.jidesoft.com/products/JIDE_Grids_Developer_Guide.pdf) which are pre-packaged with each Matlab release. By the way, `uitable` is not much more than a trimmed-down version of Jide table in the first place. There's also a number of articles on [using Jide within Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/tag/jide) out there to get you started.